# Markdown heading hierarchy

Tags: markdown

In markdown we can have subheadings but if h2 comes before h4 comes before h3 comes before h4, the last h4 is considered a subheading of h3 but the earlier h4 is considered a subheading of h2.

Is it possible to have the second h4 considered as a subheading of h2 instead of h3? Sort of like how we can jump back to a previous level with bullet points.
One example use case of this is if we want h4 to describe the properties of something, h2 to describe a topic, h3 a subtopic. After describing a subtopic, we may want to go back to describe the properties of h2 in general.

Does anyone have have any clever workarounds for this?

So far just try to avoid this sort of arrangement. If really necessary I'd create a blank h3 heading after the first h3 heading to mark a return to the previous topic. So it's clearer the second h4 does not belong to the first h3. `i.e.: h2 h4 h3 (blank h3) h4`

Comment: That isn’t how headings work in English.

Comment: No, that's just not how outlinining is done.  Do it properly.